# ServiceStack.Server: Redis server integrated withing ServiceStack lib?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, servicestack-redis

I want to clarify if I understood the ServiceStack.Server functionality correctly.

On [this page](https://docs.servicestack.net/redis-mq), ServiceStack.Server API is described, and [it states](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Server/Messaging/Redis/RedisMqServer.cs) that

> Creates a Redis MQ Server that processes each message on its own background thread

Am I correct when I then assumed that this is a standalone Redis server, so if I start this with the code below, I am running a fully fledged Redis server, meaning, no need to install the [Redis software](https://redis.io), or [Memurai](https://www.memurai.com/) or the likes?

Because, if I follow [this example](https://docs.servicestack.net/redis-mq#sharedcs), and have no other running Redis server, I get

> 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. 127.0.0.1:6379'

This line

```
var redisFactory = new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379");
```

starts a client and tries to connect to 6379 and naturally fails. The `redisFactory` is then used in the line creating the MqServer, which is odd to me:

```
var mqHost = new RedisMqServer(redisFactory, retryCount: 2);
```

If this is a standalone MQ server, then creating a client before creating and starting the server isn't going to work, which makes me think this is not an Redis MQ server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I correct when I then assumed that this is a standalone Redis server

That's an incorrect conclusion, the [Redis Server](https://redis.io/) is a distributed in-memory data structure server which just like other distributed servers like an RDBMS or MQ Broker runs in its own isolated networked process.

All ServiceStack Redis Libraries connect to a Redis Server, [Redis MQ](https://docs.servicestack.net/redis-mq) is like all other distributed [ServiceStack MQ](https://docs.servicestack.net/messaging) providers which process messages sent to a broker, in this case Redis MQ uses the Redis Server as its broker. The statement:

> Creates a Redis MQ Server that processes each message on its own background thread

Explains how Redis MQ processes the messages that it receives, where each different Message Type (i.e. Request DTO Type) processes messages in its own background thread.

Comment: So the RedisMqServer isn't a server, it's a client that connects to a Redis server. What is the difference between that and for example xRedisClientx? RedisMqServer is some form of local router, then? '%

Comment: @Ted it’s a server in that it manages its own pool of background threads to execute MQ Requests sent to it via the MQ broker in the same way that ServiceStack HTTP Services processes messages sent to it.

Comment: Right, it has threads that it dispatches to handle an incoming mq request, and routes them to the handler/service? Can I suggest to change the name at some point so it's not called an MqServer? That is very confusing.

Comment: @Ted No, it functions like a Server to process MQ Messages just like a HTTP Server manages a pool of HTTP Request Workers used to execute HTTP Requests. Don't bother wasting your time asking to break compatibility & existing code-bases by renaming classes that have existed for years, it's never going to happen.