# ServiceStack.Redis: PooledRedisClientManager and RedisManagerPool waits for prev req to finish

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

I am testing out the Redis "full duplex" communication as [shown here](https://docs.servicestack.net/redis-mq#sharedcs), and reading [the docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redismanagerpool), I thought that the `PooledRedisClientManager` as well as `RedisManagerPool` have a pool of clients, and thus being able to process several MQ messages in parallel.

However, in the test project, [found here on Github](https://github.com/tedekeroth/ServiceStackRedisFullDublexTest), it seems to me that this is not the case, or I am missing something. The solution consists of:

- EventPublisher: .NET Core WinForms application for publishing Hello DTOs to the MQ
- EventConsumer: .NET Core WinFOrms application that has Service impl for handling Hello DTOs

I added a Thread.Sleep inside the HelloService `Any(Hello req)` and when I from the EventPublisher send several Hello DTOs quickly, I was expecting them to be handled concurrently in the EventConsumer, as I thought the pool of clients would be used. This, however, doesn't seem to be the case.

The `HelloResponse`s are handled one after the other, on the same thread it seems. Please take a look at this short video:

http://somup.com/cYheY8iNml

Here, I fire off three Hello DTOs to the MQ in quick succession, and in the Output window in VS, you can see that the three DTOs are handled one after each other.

I did not find a setting in `PooledRedisClientManager` nor `RedisManagerPool` where I could specify the pool size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that the PooledRedisClientManager as well as RedisManagerPool have a pool of clients

This statement is true.

> and thus being able to process several MQ messages in parallel.

This is an invalid conclusion that's meaningless without context. The Pooled [Redis Client Managers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-client-managers) do not do any execution themselves, i.e. they only manage a pool of redis clients meaning when a client is retrieved from the pool:

```
var redis = clientsManager.GetClient();
```

The `RedisClient` (i.e. single TCP connected client to redis server) was retrieved from a pool of clients managed by the client manager and that when the client is disposed, it's returned to the pool instead of the TCP connection being terminated.

That's all that can be assumed when something is using a pool, the Client Managers don't execute Redis commands by themselves, and what the application does that uses it is specific to their implementation. The fact that they're using a pool is irrelevant, they could easily be configured to use the [BasicRedisClientManager](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#basicredisclientmanager) where no pool is used, i.e. an Application's use of a client manager doesn't make any assumption of how it's being used.

In your example project you're using [Redis MQ](https://docs.servicestack.net/redis-mq) to execute your ServiceStack Services:

```
mqHost.RegisterHandler<Hello>(base.ExecuteMessage);
mqHost.Start(); //Starts listening for messages
```

In your [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61556415/85785) you've quoted:

> Creates a Redis MQ Server that processes each message on its own background thread.

The full comment goes on to provide an example:

```
i.e. if you register 3 handlers it will create 7 background threads:
///   - 1 listening to the Redis MQ Subscription, getting notified of each new message
///   - 3x1 Normal InQ for each message handler
///   - 3x1 PriorityQ for each message handler (Turn off with DisablePriorityQueues)
```

Which explains how Redis MQ Server processes messages, i.e. each message Type is processed on its own background Thread, so if you block the message worker thread then you're blocking thread for blocking other messages for that Type (i.e. Request DTO).

```
mqHost.RegisterHandler<Hello>(base.ExecuteMessage);
```

It doesn't block other messages which are processed on their own background thread or the Priority MQ thread for that Type processing messages sent with `Priority>0`.

The [Redis MQ](https://docs.servicestack.net/redis-mq#easily-parallelize-and-multiply-your-services-throughput) docs provides an example of how you can increase the number of threads used to process each message type by specifying the `noOfThreads` when registering the handler:

#### Easily Parallelize and Multiply your services throughput

The RedisMqServer also supports spawning any number of background threads for individual requests, so if Posting to twitter was an IO intensive operation you can double the throughput by simply assigning 2 or more worker threads, e.g:

```
mqService.RegisterHandler<PostStatusTwitter>(ExecuteMessage, noOfThreads:2);
mqService.RegisterHandler<CallFacebook>(ExecuteMessage);
mqService.RegisterHandler<EmailMessage>(ExecuteMessage);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is there a way to increase the number of threads in general, that can be used for all handlers, without specifying a specific handler that should have more threads?

Comment: For each handler, 6 threads are created. Have you an idea of how many Handlers can be created without getting the OS/server into trouble? Say, 100 Handlers would spawn 600 threads, and that sounds like a lot...

Comment: @Ted You can just use C# and wrap RegisterHandler behind your own extension method that configures it how you want. Yes 600 threads is a lot & unnecessary to start with that many, start with the minimum and adjust accordingly for the messages that need it. [ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.getmaxthreads?view=netcore-3.1) returns 32767 max worker threads, 1000 completion ports thread.

Comment: But its not uncommon to have many Handlers, and with 3-6 threads per handler, it will result in many threads. So what do you mean with "start with the minimum"? If I have for example 100 Handlers, how could I stop there spawning 300+ threads? Wrapping RegisterHandler does not sound like the way, I would prefer a pool of x threads, all shared when executing a handler, not specific to a certain DTO/Handler.

Comment: @Ted I mean start with 1, then adjust accordingly to meet demand for each Message Type. MQ's aren't like HTTP's where scale is front-loaded & highly contentious, they run time-decoupled tasks over a longer period. They're also easily scalable, you can just add more servers pointing at the same MQ Broker where they're naturally load-balanced.

Comment: Since it spawns 3 + 3 threads by default, would "Start with 1" mean:  `mqHost.RegisterHandler<Hello>(base.ExecuteMessage, noOfThreads: 1);`, so this overrides the 3 `Normal InQ` and instead spawns one for the given DTO? Then, set `DisablePriorityQueues` to `true` and that would mean 1 thread, not 6?

Comment: @Ted It only starts 1 .inq + 1 .priorityq by default, the above example is the number of threads for 3x handlers. Setting `DisablePriorityQueues=true` will mean it will only start 1 .inq per handler.

Comment: Ah, the wording `3x1 Normal InQ for each message handler` confused me. 3x1=3 "for each message handler", so 3 threads for each message handler. Maybe update the text there, to like "1 Normal InQ for each message handler, 3 in total for 3 handlers"?