# ServiceStack.Redis: One thread pool for all MQ request handlers?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

In a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61581570/servicestack-redis-pooledredisclientmanager-and-redismanagerpool-waits-for-prev/#comment108938603_61583009), I ask if there is a way for the RedisMqServer to have one shared thread pool for all Handlers/DTOs, instead of 1 dedicated thread per Handler as minimum. With many Handlers, we spawn many threads, and each Handler will be limited by the number of threads assigned to it.

With for example 100 Handlers, there will be a minimum of 100 threads, but each type/handler can only process 1 request at a time (per default). I forsee situations where a specific DTO will be used a lot more than others, but I want the handlers to take the threads from the common pool instead of locking one specific handler with a call like:

```
mqService.RegisterHandler<PostStatusTwitter>(ExecuteMessage, noOfThreads:10);
```

Mythz answered and said

> You can just use C# and wrap RegisterHandler behind your own extension
>   method that configures it how you want.

I would kindly ask for some input here on as I am not sure what that would entail. I briefly review the [RedisMqServer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Server/Messaging/Redis/RedisMqServer.cs) code, but it seems to me that there needs some rewriting to achieve what I want?

Comment: The linked answer explains how Redis MQ works, i.e. not the way you're requesting for which you'd need to look elsewhere or create a solution that works the way you want. I was answering your q: "Is there a way to increase the number of threads in general, that can be used for all handlers?" thinking you wanted to DRY the registration API where you didn't want to manually specify `noOfThreads` each time.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was after creating a pool for all Handlers to use, not to specify for each handler. But then I have the answer, and that is basically "no". Feel free to add that as an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis MQ doesn't support "One thread pool for all MQ request handlers".

The [previous linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61583009/85785) explains how [Redis MQ](https://docs.servicestack.net/redis-mq) is designed where the number of threads is configurable per Message Type (i.e. Request DTO).